# Realm String greaterThan

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

Is there any way to find all (or just the next) `RealmObject`s with Strings lexicographically greater than the target?

Something like

```
MyEntry next = realm.where(MyEntry.class)
        .greaterThan("name", current)
        .findAllSorted("name")
        .first();
```

which did not work, because `greaterThan` is not implemented for `String`s.

Comment: Created https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a non-db-workaround, you can use

```
List<MyEntry> l = realm.where(MyEntry.class)
    .findAllSorted("name");
int pos = l.indexOf(entryWithName);
MyEntry next = l.get((pos+1)%l.size());
```

This does the searching outside of the db. Possibly not as well-performing, and not as readable, but it should work.

Comment: Nice solution, I like it. And I don't know of a better one.